# Android Kotlin - How to extend ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, extend

I'd like my ConstaintLayout to carry extra additional properties, but I have trouble extending it. More precisely I have trouble putting correct constructor into

```
class myCL(): ConstraintLayout(???) {
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The constructor you really need is the one with all arguments:

```
class myCL(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) :
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
}
```

if you want to implement all three constructors without much hassle you can use `@JvmOverloads` and use sensible defaults.

```
class myCL @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
}
```

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Comment: Perfect, the constructor overload annotation worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

To make sure you don't get any quirks in behavior, you should implement it like this.

```
class myCL: ConstraintLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?,
                @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this to restict to only one `super` call --

```
class MyConstraintLayout: ConstraintLayout {

   constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
   constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, -1)
   constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
}
```