# How to extend ConstraintLayout in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm trying to extend ConstraintLayout for use with a compound component in Kotlin. Most of the examples I've found are [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632338/android-kotlin-how-to-extend-constraintlayout), where the constructor has 3 parameters. However, there's a [fourth constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#ConstraintLayout(Context,%20AttributeSet,%20int,%20int)) that takes another parameter, defStyleRes. What's the correct default value to use for it? [Based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784919/9633447) I think 0 works, similar to defStyleAttr.
Here is what I think the final code should look like:

```
class ClockButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
private val attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
private val defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
private val defStyleRes: Int = 0) : ConstraintLayout(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
```

Comment: In the majority of cases when subclassing a View, you only need to create the two-argument constructor and call through to the super-constructor with two arguments. The other overloads aren’t needed for the view to work from an XML layout.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Do you mean that if I'm only going to inflate using an XML layout I only have to worry about the context and attributeSet parameters?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: You only need to implement the three- and four-argument constructors if you want to support default styles/attributes and also allow people to specify _other_ default styles/attrs. If all you want is simple inflation from XML, the two-arg constructor is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: You *can* use `0` for the third and fourth arguments, but in my opinion you are better off just exposing a two-argument constructor and calling into the superclass's own two-argument constructor.

---

When inflating a view from XML, only the two-argument constructor is ever called. Therefore, the one-, three-, and four-argument constructors are only relevant if you call them from Java/Kotlin code.

If you look at, for example, the source code for `MaterialButton`, you will find that its two-argument constructor looks like this:

```
public MaterialButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.materialButtonStyle);
}
```

And it has a corresponding three-argument constructor:

```
public MaterialButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(wrap(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, DEF_STYLE_RES), attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // approx. 30 lines omitted
}
```

It does not specify a four-argument constructor at all.

The benefit of setting things up this way comes in two parts.

1. You can style all `MaterialButton` instances in your app by specifying the `materialButtonStyle` attribute in your theme. See [this documentation](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#theming-buttons) for more (search for "using default style theme attributes").
2. Future developers can subclass `MaterialButton` and specify a *different* default style attribute in their two-argument constructors:

```
public class MySpecialButton extends MaterialButton {

    public MySpecialButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.mySpecialStyle);
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you do not care about these default styles/attributes, you can ignore the three- and four-argument constructors altogether, and simply call through to the parent's two-argument constructor:

```
class MyCompoundView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs)
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks for taking the time to explain it